# Animating along an elliptical path in OpenGL

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, drawing

I am trying to make a red circle follow the path of a semi-circle using the DDA algorithm in OpenGL. I almost have it, though the circle is slightly offset on its X-axis, which increases as the angle of the semi-circle increases.

[image]
[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Here's my code:

```
scrPt movecircle (scrPt p1, scrPt p2)
{
    scrPt circlePos;

    float angle, x = p1.x, y = p1.y, vectorX, vectorY;

    // Get tahe x distance between the two points
    int dx = p2.x - p1.x, steps;

    // Get the y distance between the two points
    int dy = p2.y - p1.y;

    // Get the length between the points
    float length = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    if (fabs (dx) > fabs (dy)) 
    steps = fabs (dx); 
    else 
        steps = fabs (dy);

    // calculate the direction
    float xIncrement = float (dx) / float (steps); 
    float yIncrement = float (dy) / float (steps); 

    if (nextPos == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            angle = PI * i / steps;
            vectorX = x + (length / 2) * cos(angle + theta);
            vectorY = y + dy / 2 + (length / 2) * sin(angle + theta);
            circlePos.x = round(vectorX - length / 2);
            circlePos.y = round(vectorY);
            drawCircle (circlePos.x, circlePos.y);
            drawArch();
            glFlush();
            usleep(3000);
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            drawCircle (round(x),round(y));
            glFlush();
            usleep(3000);
            x += xIncrement; 
            y += yIncrement;
        }
    }

    return circlePos;
}
```

Comment: what is `nextPos`?

Comment: It's a global integer that stores whether the circle is travelling from P1->P2 (via the straight line) or P2->P1 via the ellipse

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of errors in the for-loop that were causing the issue. I needed to change

this:

```
vectorX = x + (length / 2) * cos(angle + theta);
```

to this:

```
vectorX = x + (dx / 2) + (length / 2) * cos(angle + theta);
```

and this:

```
circlePos.x = round(vectorX - (length / 2));
```

to this:

```
circlePos.x = round(vectorX);
```